# Can't Horizontally Align

Tags: html, css, flexbox, footer

I am trying to horizontally align the social icons in my footer but I can't figure it out.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'free pixel';
    src: url(../assets/fontface/FreePixel.ttf);
    font-style: normal;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
}
/* x Global & General x */

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    background-color: black;
    font-family: 'free pixel';
}


.logo{
    color: green;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.k-hole-logo{
    color: green;
}

.nav-links{
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
width: 30%;

}

.nav-links a{
    color: green;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.nav-links li {
    list-style: none;
}

.burger {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: green;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
   .nav-links{
       width: 60%;
   }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    body{
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .nav-links{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        height: 92vh;
        top: 8vh;
        background-color: black;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 33%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }
    .nav-links li{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .burger{
        display: block;
    }
}

.nav-active{
    transform: translateX(0%);
}

@keyframes navLinkFade{
    from{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}

.toggle .line1 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}
.toggle .line2 {
    opacity: 0;
}
.toggle .line3 {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
}

#social-icons {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#social-icons ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#social-icons ul li a{
    display: block;
    color: green;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I have included all the CSS in case it is some issue with priority and I've done something in a previous section that is wrong. I am trying to center the social icons and have them be horizontally aligned with a bit of space between them...the section of the HTML I am trying to alter looks like this:

```
<footer>
    <div id="social-icons">
      <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram-square"></i></a>
     </li>
   </div>
  </ul>
</div>
</footer>
```

Thanks! I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove the `display: block` from the `<a>` style, that's working against you.

Second, you want to declare a style for each `<li>` that says you want them to be displayed inline.

Third, you want to tell the whole `#socialicons <div>` to display the text centered on the page.

Here's what I'd change the CSS to:

```
#social-icons {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#social-icons ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#social-icons li {
  display: inline;
}

#social-icons ul li a{
    color: green;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to align the items using [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) CSS properties, you need to apply `display: flex;` in the element wrapping the items you want to align.

In your specific case modify the `#social-icons ul` to include `display: flex` and this should do the trick.

```
#social-icons ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
display: flex;
}
```